# How to make vim text bold?

Tags: vimrc, highlight

In order to have my vim text always bold, I found this config in stackoverflow:

```
 :hi MyGroup cterm=bold
 :match MyGroup /./
```

But somehow, it has messed up search highlighting. It is no longer highlighted, but it shouldn't have any effect on that, since it is only changing the cterm property, and not ctermfg/ctermbg.

I thought if I added the following I would fix it, but it didn't:

```
 :hi Search ctermbg=yellow ctermfg=black term=bold cterm=bold
```

Any solutions?

Comment: In [`:help :match`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%3Amatch) it states that "the {group} highlighting still applies when a character is to be highlighted for 'hlsearch'..." Essentially it overrides searches. So `match` might not be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Despite this seeming like a fairly simple task, I can't think of straight forward way to do this. The best way I know how is to create your own color file and change all the `cterm`s to bold.

If you're using one of the default color schemes you can find it at `.../Vim/vim##/colors` where `##` is the version you're running.

Answer (score 0):

I do this in GUI Vim by setting the font to a bold font:

```
:set guifont=Menlo-Bold:h13
```

To choose various fonts just use `:set guifont=*` and you'll get a dialog chooser. After you've chosen your preferred font use `:set guifont?` to see the font specification that you need to put in your vimrc.

For console Vim fandom wiki says "Console Vim uses whatever font the console/terminal is using. ... Consult the documentation or manpages for your terminal... Vim cannot use a different font than the rest of the terminal." https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Change_font

Therefore to use a bold font in console Vim, change the font of your terminal to a bold font.

Comment: Terminal vim doesnt support guifont.

Comment: Not sure what you mean—i guess, but then all the text in the terminal would be bold?

Comment: I think that's what the OP is requesting, @D.BenKnoble.